# Simple chat working but display same messages over and over

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, chat, long-polling

My question is how do i stop the loop over and over on the same messages?

Here is my [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery)code:

```
waitForMsg();
setInterval(waitForMsg, 5000);

function waitForMsg() {
  $.ajax({
    url: CI_ROOT + 'welcome/getMessage',
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    async: true,
    cache: false,

    success: function(data) {
      $.each(data, function(key, value) {

        var msg_id = value.msg_id;
        var timestamp = value.posted_at;
        var user_msg = value.msg;
        var user_name = value.name;


        $(".chat_log").append(
          "<p data-id=" + msg_id + ">" + "<b>" + user_name + "</b>" + ': ' + user_msg + ' | Posted: ' + "<span data-livestamp=" + timestamp + "></span>" + ', msg ID: ' + msg_id + "</p>"
        );


      });
    }
  });
}
```

Here is from where i get [json](/questions/tagged/json) `"welcome/getMessage"`:

```
[{
    "name": "Dima",
    "msg": "i don't know i feel bad today :(",
    "posted_at": "2015-08-29 02:50:31",
    "msg_id": "12"
  },
  {
    "name": "toma",
    "msg": "whats wrong?",
    "posted_at": "2015-08-29 02:48:59",
    "msg_id": "11"
  },
  {
    "name": "toma",
    "msg": "hey",
    "posted_at": "2015-08-29 02:46:11",
    "msg_id": "10"
  }
]
```

And result is:

```
Dima: i don't know i feel bad today :( | Posted: 3 hours ago, msg ID: 12
toma: whats wrong? | Posted: 3 hours ago, msg ID: 11
toma: hey | Posted: 3 hours ago, msg ID: 10
Dima: i don't know i feel bad today :( | Posted: 3 hours ago, msg ID: 12
toma: whats wrong? | Posted: 3 hours ago, msg ID: 11
toma: hey | Posted: 3 hours ago, msg ID: 10
Dima: i don't know i feel bad today :( | Posted: 3 hours ago, msg ID: 12
toma: whats wrong? | Posted: 3 hours ago, msg ID: 11
toma: hey | Posted: 3 hours ago, msg ID: 10
Dima: i don't know i feel bad today :( | Posted: 3 hours ago, msg ID: 12
toma: whats wrong? | Posted: 3 hours ago, msg ID: 11
toma: hey | Posted: 3 hours ago, msg ID: 10
```

I need somehow to compare `msg` id in client side and [json](/questions/tagged/json)or server side.

I would be glad for any help thanks!

Dimak.

Comment: You should send a timestamp or the last message id with the request and return only new messages..

Comment: you mean to get latest msg id displayed in chat and check if in json is a greater msg id and then display another msg with new id?

Comment: I mean to store the last message id in a variable (let's call it `lastMsg`) and send it in each request.. Your response shouldn't include any message with a lower or equal id. Every time you receive new messages, you have to update `lastMsg` with the new one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my new [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)solution.

https://jsfiddle.net/dannyjhonston/tvcy4k6r/1/

Updated...

```js
$(function() {
  var messages = [{
    "name": "Dima",
    "msg": "i don't know i feel bad today :(",
    "posted_at": "2015-08-29 02:50:31",
    "msg_id": "12"
  }, {
    "name": "toma",
    "msg": "whats wrong?",
    "posted_at": "2015-08-29 02:48:59",
    "msg_id": "11"
  }, {
    "name": "toma",
    "msg": "hey",
    "posted_at": "2015-08-29 02:46:11",
    "msg_id": "10"
  }];

  $("#btnSendMessage").on("click", function() {
    // Adds new message object to message's array.
    messages.push({
      name: "NewUser",
      msg: $("#txtMessage").val(),
      posted_at: new Date(),
      msg_id: new Date().getTime()
    });
    console.log(messages);
  });

  var oldCountMessages = messages.length; // Previously, you need to save the messages's length.

  var newMessageIndex = 0; // Declare a numeric variable to use like new index to show a new chat message.

  // You need to print the messages, only once.
  for (var i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {
    $("#chatMessages").append("<div class=\"chat\"><span class=\"user\">" + messages[i].name + "</span><br /> " + messages[i].msg + "</div>");
  }
  // Self-looping function to show check if there are new messages.
  (function loop() {
    // Checking if there are new messages.
    if (messages.length > oldCountMessages) {
      // Initializing newMessageIndex with the new message index, to show it.
      newMessageIndex = messages.length - 1;
      // Printing only the new message.
      $("#chatMessages").append("<div class=\"chat\"><span class=\"user\">" + messages[newMessageIndex].name + "</span><br /> " + messages[newMessageIndex].msg + "</div>");
    }
    // Updating oldCountMessages variable for the next verification in the looping function.
    oldCountMessages = messages.length;
    setTimeout(loop, 1000); // Checking the server every second. 
  })();
});
```

```css
#chatMessages {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 0.8em;
}

.chat {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#BED4E6, #FFFFFF);
  border: solid 1px #84A8D6;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.chat:hover {
  background-image: linear-gradient(#FFFFFF, #BED4E6);
}

.user {
  background-color: inherit;
  color: #224577;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="txtMessage" type="text" value="" />
<button id="btnSendMessage" type="button">Send message</button>
<hr />
<div id="chatMessages"></div>
```

Comment: i did something like that but i need to check if there is a new msgs if so then display it else nothing showed so do i need to create another ajax to get last msg or something?

Comment: I've made a very simple demo only to show you an idea to start. This is my JSFiddle.
Try to check it. 

https://jsfiddle.net/dannyjhonston/tvcy4k6r/

Comment: working great! but if you remove the '$(".chat_log").html("");' its actually removing everything inside the div or whatever is there. its keep spamming with same messages if i remove that line, is there a way to make it without it?

Comment: I know, that's the limitation in this code.

Yeah, but you could implement realtime chat application with [link](http://socket.io/demos/chat/) or SignalR for ASP.NET, but you will need to develop in Back-end, everything.

This technology uses sockets connections, where the server listens to clients in realtime. So if any user sends a message to other user, the server, automatically will show the message to this user, without long polling connection with setTimout javascript function. It's very efficient.

Check my updated javascript solution.

Comment: awesome working great! and last thing, for example if you watching the chat and i send msg you didn't receive it live or i doin something wrong then!

Comment: In this code:
1. When you click on the Send message button, saves the message object in to the "messages" array variable. This is instantaneously.
 
$("#btnSendMessage").on("click"... 

2. The looping function checks for every second, if there is a new message. 
 
if(messages.length > oldCountMessages)
 
3. If "messages.length" is greater than "oldCountMessages", executes $("#chatMessages").append("<div..., to show the new message in the UI. It's not real time exactly. 

4. Finally, updates the "oldCountMessages" variable with the "messages.length", for the next verification.